# Extract whole schema from oracle database to another (java) (automation)

Tags: oracle, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, liquibase, schema-compare

I am trying to find a solution that I can hopefully implement a regression test from one oracle database against another oracle DB via data.

Example: Database A adds a table, I want to take the data from database A and import it into database schema B. This will ultimately fail and I will know there was a change of some kind and can correct it.

I would like to automate this in Jenkins is possible for a nightly test. I found several paid versions but at this point in the project that is not necessary.

I am using Liquibase but I was unable to find a plugin for Jenkins. I am aware Sql Developer can do this but I want this to be automated.

If anyone has any past experiences or know any tools I would great appreciate the advice.

Comment: I don't know Jenkins at all, but this smells like a good test case for using Hibernate /JPA. You can read the schema from one database, create the models and then create another database based on this models.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered [Oracle Data Pump](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm)? With it you can export data and/or schema metadata from one database and import it into another. There is a command line interface and a PL/SQL API.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [liquibase runner](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Liquibase+Runner) plugin. Have you tried that?

Alternatively, you could install liquibase on the jenkins build agent and just execute it as a command line tool.

Comment: The runner plugin is no longer supported according to its wiki. I wish I could use it, it appears it’s what I need. I want to find out if the data from DB 1 will successfully import to DB 2 with no errors. I know liquibase has a diff but not a data import like the use case I need. Am I wrong?

Comment: Liquibase is really best-suited for structure, not data. I upvoted the answer that mentions Oracle Data Pump.

Answer (score 0):

You might be not need to have plugin for Jenkins but simple Gradle task to run in Jenkinsfile.
I use Gradle plugin with config like:

```
task updateSQL(type: JavaExec) {

    group = "Liquibase"
    classpath configurations.liquibase
    main = "liquibase.integration.commandline.Main"

    args "--changeLogFile=***/changelog-current.xml"
    args ****
}
```

This valid for plugin: 'net.saliman:gradle-liquibase-plugin:XXX'